# Array as parameter (PHP) : Error :Undefined variable

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to call a function and pass an array and other variables to it. this is the code I use to do that :

```
function fnGetElementsById($ArrCols, $tableName, $id) {

    while($arrCols[$i])
    {
        if($i != 0)
        {
            $sql = $sql.',';
        }
        $sql = $sql.$arrCols[$i].' ';
        $i++;
    }  }
```

the while line is the error or notice line and when I test with var_dump, the array is empty.

the calling code :

```
$arrCols = array(
    0=>'marque', 
    1=>'prix'
);
$CDB->fnGetElementsById($arrCols, 'Portables', $_POST['id1']);
```

thank you

Comment: Is there an error message? What does it say?

Comment: Undefined variable...It's a notice but the array I got is empty. that's the problem

Comment: Sooo, what is it you want to do again? You are trying to pass an array into a function and the result of the function into the array. That doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: Is it `$arrCols` or `$ArrCols` ?

Comment: @user3375869: Do you see that the name of the parameter and the `while` condition use different casing?

Comment: @MLeFevre: It's both. That's the (biggest) problem.

Comment: it works, thanks a lot @MLeFevre I didn't see the 'A' and it was driving me crazy. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined `$i` before the while loop is invoked.  Therefore you are basically trying this:

```
while($arrCols[null]) {
```

Also your parameter is `$ArrCols` and the variable name in the while conditional is `$arrCols` (lowercase first letter).

You need to fix both of these.

Answer (score 0):

You have a case issue.

```
function fnGetElementsById($ArrCols, $tableName, $id) {
    while($arrCols[$i])
```

Should be

```
function fnGetElementsById($arrCols, $tableName, $id) {
    while($arrCols[$i])
```

Notice change from `ArrCols` to `arrCols`.

Also you did not initialize your `$i` variable.
Please set it to `0` before using.

Comment: I did defined $i I just didn't copy it with the question. But for the 'Arr' and 'arr'. You are right and now it works. Thank you